# Doing an operation with an int and a long

Tags: int, long-integer

I need to get `x%16`, where x is a `long`. My compiler gives me the error

> "possible loss of precision. required: int; found: long."

How can I get around this?

Edit: Whoops, I didn't realize I could just cast the whole thing as an int, I thought it could only cast the long as an int (which would be bad) to get it to cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can try:

1. `x % 16L`
2. `x & 0x0000000FL` // You don't need the zeroes; 0xFL should work.

Both these techniques result in a `long` without losing precision. If you want an `int`, just cast x to `int` before operating on it, and remove the L suffixes.